# Debugger is referring to java file at some other location in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

While running my code in debug mode, stack trace in Eclipse gives some other line number, while that line number does not exist in my code. 
I have installed JadClipse plugin in Eclipse which converts .class into .java. But the line number mismatch is happening while debugging. Please provide your valuable inputs behind this issue. Thanks.

Comment: More info is needed. Stacktrace is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the JD-Eclipse plugin? I think the earlier version had a problem retaining line number information on decompilation. Try using the [JDEclipse Realign](http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/). This should give you the right navigation from the stack trace.